# Why "Using python interact with Operating System"'s week 1 Qwiklabs Assessment: Working with Python code is not correctly working

Tags: python, coursera-api

On Google IT automation with python specialization "Using python interact with Operating System"'s week 1 Qwiklabs Assessment: Working with Python 3rd module is not properly work

on ~/scripts directory :
network.py code

```
    #!usr/bin/env python3
import requests
import socket

def check_localhost():
    localhost = socket.gethostbyname('localhost')
    print(localhost)
    if localhost == '127.0.0.1':
        return True

    return False
def check_connectivity():
    request = requests.get("http://www.google.com")
    responses = request.status_code
    print(responses)
    if responses == 200:
        return True

    return False
```

By using this code I make "Create a new Python module
"

but Qwiklab show me that I cannot properly write code.!!!

now what is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I am responding with this piece here because I noticed a lot of folks taking this course ***"Using Python to interact with the Operating System"*** on Coursera do have similar issues with writing the Python function `check_localhost` and `check_connectivity`. Please, copy these functions to your VM and try again.
To ping the web and also check whether the local host is correctly configured, we will `import requests` module and socket module.
Next, write a function `check_localhost`, which checks whether the local host is correctly configured. And we do this by calling the `gethostbyname` within the function.
`localhost = socket.gethostbyname('localhost')` 
The above function translates a hostname to IPv4 address format. Pass the parameter localhost to the function `gethostbyname`. The result for this function should be **127.0.0.1**.
Edit the function check_localhost so that it returns true if the function returns **127.0.0.1**.

```
import requests 
import socket 
#Function to check localhost
def check_localhost():
    localhost = socket.gethostbyname('localhost')
    if localhost == "127.0.0.1":
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Now, we will write another function called `check_connectivity`. This checks whether the computer can make successful calls to the internet.
A request is when you ping a website for information. The Requests library is designed for this task. You will use the request module for this, and call the GET method by passing a `http://www.google.com` as the parameter.
`request = requests.get("http://www.google.com")`
This returns the website's status code. This status code is an integer value. Now, assign the result to a response variable and check the status_code attribute of that variable. It should return 200.
Edit the function check_connectivity so that it returns true if the function returns 200 status_code.

```
#Function to check connectivity
def check_connectivity():
    request = requests.get("http://www.google.com")
    if request.status_code == 200:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Once you have finished editing the file, `press Ctrl-o, Enter, and Ctrl-x to exit`.
When you're done, **Click Check my progress to verify the objective**.

Answer (score 3):

I was also using a similar code, although It was getting executed fine in the lab terminal, however, it was not getting successfully verified. I contacted the support team using support chat and they provided a similar but relatively efficient code that worked ;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests
import socket
localhost = socket.gethostbyname('localhost')
request = requests.get("http://www.google.com")
def check_localhost():
    if localhost == "127.0.0.1":
        return True
def check_connectivity():
    if request.status_code == 200:
        return True
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the same code of yours to check what's the problem in the code, but your code successfully passed the qwiklabs check.

I think there is something wrong, Did you retry again by end this lab session and create another session just to check if this is something wrong with their end.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Ankit24007. But this is a matter of sorrow that I  try this qwiklab more than 7 times in 3 different device then I also see the youtube video. More interestingly this code is also successfully work for 4 th task of this assessment but unfortunately not work for this 3rd on. Every time I score 15/20 and end this lab :)

Answer (score 1):

It's so easy, in this case, the shebang line would be /usr/bin/env python3.

you type a wrong shebang line:

```
#!usr/bin/env python3
```

But you should type:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Add a shebang line to define where the interpreter is located.

Answer (score 0):

It can be written like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests
import socket

def check_localhost():
    localhost = socket.gethostbyname('localhost')
    return localhost == "127.0.0.1"

def check_connectivity():
    request = requests.get("http://www.google.com")
    return request.status_code() == 200
```

Answer (score -1):

This script does work even if you are facing the issue in the post:

```
import requests
import socket
def check_localhost():
    localhost = socket.gethostbyname('localhost')
    return True # or return localhost == "127.0.0.1"
def check_connectivity():
    request = requests.get("http://www.google.com")
    return True #or return request==200
```

What could be wrong with your code? The verification system is faulty and doesn't accept:

-tab instead of 4 spaces as right identation

-spaces between lines

Answer (score -1):

```
#!usr/bin/env python3
import requests
import socket
def check_localhost():    
    localhost = socket.gethostbyname('localhost')
    print(localhost)
    if localhost == '127.0.0.1':
        return True
def check_connectivity():
    request = requests.get("http://www.google.com")
    responses = request.status_code()
    print(responses)
    if responses == '200':
        return True
```

Comment: The main Error is at   responses=request.status_code()  the brackets are must.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score -1):

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3

    import requests
    import socket

    def check_localhost():
        localhost = socket.gethostbyname('localhost')
        if localhost == "127.0.0.1":
            return True
    def check_connectivity():
        request = requests.get("http://www.google.com")
        if request.status_code() == 200:
            return True
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).